# Read excel file in R: problem with columns' labels and data/hour format

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have an `excel` file like this:

[image]

which I tried to read by using:

```
library(xlsx)
df <- read.xlsx("2021.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)
```

However, I obtained a result that I do not like very much

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Twitter = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jack", 
"John", "User"), class = "factor"), NA. = structure(c(5L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Hello world", "Hello!", "I'm a text", 
"I'm an example", "Tweet"), class = "factor"), NA..1 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("44293", "44294", "Date"), class = "factor"), 
NA..2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0.490277777777778", 
"0.552083333333333", "Hour"), class = "factor"), NA..3 = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("3", "4", "x"), class = "factor"), 
NA..4 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("6", 
"7", "y"), class = "factor"), NA..5 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("no", "yes", "z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -5L))
```

i.e.,

```
> df
  Twitter            NA. NA..1             NA..2 NA..3 NA..4 NA..5
1    User          Tweet  Date              Hour     x     y     z
2    Jack    Hello world 44293 0.490277777777778     3     7   yes
3    Jack     I'm a text 44293 0.490277777777778     3     7   yes
4    John I'm an example 44294 0.552083333333333     4     6    no
5    John         Hello! 44294 0.552083333333333     4     6   yes
```

This is not the desired result. First, the date and the hour are wrong. Second, columns' labels are strange (Twitter, Na., NA..1 and so on). The correct labels are instead in the first rwo of the dataframe. I would like to obtain labels like, e.g., the following:

```
Twitter.User, Twitter.Tweet, Twitter.Date, Twitter.Hour, Twitter.x, Twitter.y, Twitter.z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `read.xlsx("2021.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, startRow = 2)`